# Using GREATEST in WHERE

Tags: mysql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

As part of a vehicle log for several vehicles in mysql (MariaDB) I need to find the row which contains the greatest mileage for each vehicle with one query.
The table contains columns: id, vehicle_id, km_start, km_end.
So the task is to find the row with max(max(km_start,km_end)) for each vehicle_id.

I found that

```
SELECT id 
FROM log 
WHERE (vehicle_id,km_end) IN (SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(IFNULL(km_end,0)) 
                              FROM log 
                              GROUP BY vehicle_id)
```

will do the job if km_end is always present. However, if km_end has not yet been entered it will contain 0. Therefore the maximum mileage might as well be in km_start.

I tried

```
SELECT id 
FROM log 
WHERE (vehicle_id,km_max) IN (SELECT vehicle_id, 
                                     GREATEST(MAX(IFNULL(km_start,0)), 
                                              MAX(IFNULL(km_end,0))) AS km_max 
                              FROM log GROUP BY vehicle_id)
```

which returns
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'km_max' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because the value list in the WHERE on the outside of the subquery should refer to the fields in `log`. You may be able to use a JOIN instead:

```
SELECT id 
FROM log AS l
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT vehicle_id
      , GREATEST(MAX(IFNULL(km_start,0)), MAX(IFNULL(km_end,0))) AS km_max 
   FROM log 
   GROUP BY vehicle_id
) AS lMax
ON l.vehicle_id = lMax.vehicle_id 
AND lMax.km_max IN (l.km_start, l.km_end)
```

---

Also, I'd maybe change this
`GREATEST(MAX(IFNULL(km_start,0)), MAX(IFNULL(km_end,0)))`
to
`GREATEST(IFNULL(MAX(km_start,0)), IFNULL(MAX(km_end,0)))`; I'm not sure if it entirely matters, but intuitively I think it might get better performance. *Most aggregate functions ignore nulls, and only return null if only null values were encountered; so the only time you should need to worry about null is after the max is calculated. (If you were using average and wanted to count nulls as 0's it would be a different matter though.)*

---

Alternatively, this may work as well:

```
WHERE (vehicle_id
       , GREATEST(MAX(IFNULL(km_start,0)), MAX(IFNULL(km_end,0)))
      ) IN (SELECT vehicle_id
                   , GREATEST(MAX(IFNULL(km_start,0)), MAX(IFNULL(km_end,0))) AS km_max 
            FROM log 
            GROUP BY vehicle_id
           )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Uueerdo.
Your first proposal works like charm.
Changing the order of MAX and IFNULL throws
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0)), IFNULL(MAX(km_end,0))) AS km_max FROM log GROUP BY vehicle_id) AS lMax ON l' at line 1
Your second proposal (Alternatively...) throws
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Will use the first one.

Comment: Re: swapping the IFNULL and MAX; you needed to move the second argument for IFNULL as well _i.e. `IFNULL(MAX(x),0)`, not `IFNULL(MAX(x,0))`_. Re: the second suggestion; oh yeah, can't aggregate in a WHERE; you _could_ put in a HAVING (but some would consider it an abuse of the language to use a HAVING without a GROUP BY in the same context.)

Comment: Tried IFNULL(MAX(x),0) istead of IFNULL(MAX(x,0)). It works now. Thank you.